# I need to remove a single array within a 2d array and form associative array

Tags: php, laravel

I'm getting this in my post,

```
[{"master":"80216","assign":["80491","80514","80575"]}]
```

Required Output

```
[{"master":"80216","assign":"80491"}]
[{"master":"80216","assign":"80514"}]
[{"master":"80216","assign":"80575"}]
```

Comment: You will need to add the code which generates this data for us to be able to help.

Comment: This is not a code writing service. You're expected to attempt to solve these kinds of problems before asking a question. If you have attempted then show us the code of your attempt (it does not have to work) and someone can help based on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick. No explanation is needed. You can get it by going through the code.

```
$input  = []; # your data array

foreach ($input as $item) {
    $master = $item["master"];
    foreach ($item["assign"] as $assign) {
        $output[] = [
            "master" => $master,
            "assign" => $assign
        ];
    }
}
```